# script sobre o programa R

Tags: r

Estou usando o R para extrair dados no formato `.h5`. Estou conseguindo.
Porém, são dados de 200 anos, e mensais.

Por enquanto, eu consigo só chamar através do programa um arquivo de cada mês por vez, mas eu preciso conseguir fazer um script onde eu consiga extrair os dados de cada arquivo para todos os anos, sem precisar fazer de um por um.
Meu script está assim:

```
library(hdf5)
mydata = hdf5load ("teste_200-Q-2000-01-00-000000-g01.h5",load=FALSE)
mydata$AGB_PY
names(mydata)
```

Tentei concatenar e ficou deste jeito:

```
library(hdf5)
ED<-c ( "01.h5","02.h5","03.h5","04.h5","05.h5","06.h5", "07.h5", "08.h5", "09.h5","10.h5","11.h5","12.h5")
ED
names(mydata)
for(i in 01:12)sum(mydata$AGB_PY)
resu<-sum(mydata$AGB_PY)
resu
agbyear = rep(NA,times=12)
for (i in 1:12){
  mydata = hdf5load(ED[i],load=FALSE)
  agbyear[i] = sum(mydata$AGB_PY)}
agbyear
mydata$AGB_PY<- edit(data.frame(agbyear))
write.table(agbyear,"agbyear.csv", row.names=FALSE  , sep  = ",")
```

Mas eu queria saber como faço para ele saber que tem que chamar todos os arquivos `.h5` e distinguir os meses e os anos.

**Edição:**

Respondendo as perguntas, o formato de cada arquivo é este:

```
teste_200-Q-2001-01-00-000000-g01.h5
teste_200-Q-2001-02-00-000000-g01.h5
teste_200-Q-2001-03-00-000000-g01.h5
```

... e assim por diante , para 200 anos, de 2000 a 2200.

Então, como o mês fica no "meio" do nome do arquivo, como poderia chamar tosos os arquivos do mês?

Tentei assim: "_.h5" , mas não funcionou. tentei também "*.h5" também não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código parece estar quase 100%, faltou apenas você montar o nome de cada arquivo completamente. Você pode fazer isso utilizando a função `paste`, ou `paste0` para não precisar definir o argumento `sep = ""`.

Resolvendo apenas para os meses, que você já tinha começado, e retirando as linhas que você colocou apenas para observar os dados, ficaria assim:

```
library(hdf5)

ED <- c("01.h5","02.h5","03.h5","04.h5","05.h5","06.h5", "07.h5", "08.h5", "09.h5","10.h5","11.h5","12.h5")

resu <- sum(mydata$AGB_PY)
agbyear <- rep(NA, times=12)
basename <- "teste_200-Q-2000-01-00-000000-g"

for (i in 1:12) {
  mydata <- hdf5load(paste0(basename, ED[i]), load=FALSE)
  agbyear[i] <- sum(mydata$AGB_PY)
}

write.table(agbyear, "agbyear.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Alguns pontos que podem ser destacados:

1. Talvez o melhor não seja digitar manualmente o final dos arquivos em um vetor (ou criar todos os nomes). Uma saída seria utilizar algo como `list.files(pattern="\\.h5")`, que retorna um vetor com os nomes dos arquivos `.h5` no working directory.
2. Evite utilizar `edit()`. Se você alterar os dados manualmente, o código fica irreprodutível. Procure maneiras de fazer as alterações que você quer com código.
3. Ao invés do `for`, poderíamos usar um `sapply`, que é um jeito mais idiomático de ser fazer a mesma coisa, sem precisar criar o vetor `agbyear` anteriormente.

Por exemplo:

```
allfiles <- paste0(basename, ED)
agbyear <- sapply(allfiles, function(i) {
  mydata <- hdf5load(i, load=FALSE)
  sum(mydata$AGB_PY)
}
```

Apesar do ponto **1**, podemos pegar o gancho do `sapply` e do `allfiles` para criar todos os arquivos de vários anos, para vários meses. Não ficou claro na pergunta se os meses realmente são a parte em `ED` (imagino que sim), e qual é o intervalo de anos. Mas para o intervalo 2000 - 2015, poderíamos fazer assim:

```
allfiles <- as.vector(sapply(anos, function(a) {
  paste0("teste_200-Q-", a, "-01-00-000000-g", ED)
}))
```

Assim, teríamos 16*12 = 192 nomes de arquivos. Mas se os arquivos estiverem organizados, talvez a melhor opção ainda seja utilizar o `list.files()`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu vou tentar te ajudar e preciso de algumas informações.
Como você define o mês e o ano?
Qual é o padrão do nome dos arquivos?
Quais os dados contidos nesse componente AGB_PY?

Você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
    # Função para ler os arquivos h5, recebendo um diretório como argumento.

    lerH5 <- function( diretorio ){
    # sempre caregar a biblioteca hdf5load quando chamar a função
    require(hdf5)

    listaArquivos <- list.files( diretorio )

      for( i in 1:length(listaArquivos)){
         #realizar a extração dos dados que deseja aqui, para cada arquivo
      }
    }
```

Espero ter contribuído de alguma forma.